# Ruby mysql2 - is there a way to kill a query?

Tags: ruby, mysql2

Using the mysql2 gem to execute SQL, is there a way to kill a query after I've requested it to be executed, either because I executed it asynchronously, or a timeout or other error has returned control to the program?

Answer (score 0):

I know you can send `KILL id`, where `id` is the ID of the process you want to kill, but I'm not sure how you know which ID to kill.  You can get a list of all IDs with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` (or `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`).